# How do aggregate only some rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by

I am working on a pandas dataframe with **millions of rows** containing some transactions information.

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID': ['Afiliates','Afiliates','Afiliates','Afiliates','Afiliates','Afiliates'],
'partner': ['Amazon','Awin','Amazon','Amazon','Amazon','Amazon'],
'date': [dt.date(2022,11,1),dt.date(2022,11,5),dt.date(2022,11,1),dt.date(2022,11,10),dt.date(2022,11,15),dt.date(2022,11,1)],
'customerID' : ['01','01','01','01','02','01'],
'brand' : ['Amazon','Ponto','Amazon','Amazon','Amazon','Amazon'],
'sku':['firetv','alexa','alexa','firetv','firetv','firetv'],
'transactionID': ['51000','55000','51000','53000','54000','51000'],
'gmv' : [10,50,30,40,50,60] })
```

I am working on a way to aggregate some rows that are related (same transactionID), keeping all columns and structure.

I´ve tried to execute a groupby on all columns and some aggregate function over brand (list) and gmv (sum)

```
df.groupby(['ProductID','partner','date','customerID','brand','transactionID']).aggregate({'sku':list, 'gmv':'sum'})
```

My question is, how to a create a list of "unique" itens, as you can see, e.g., 'firetv' could appear several times on the same row after aggregation.

[image: output example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set()` to remove duplicates, for example:

```py
x = df.groupby(
    ["ProductID", "partner", "date", "customerID", "brand", "transactionID"]
).aggregate({"sku": lambda x: list(set(x)), "gmv": "sum"})

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                          sku  gmv
ProductID partner date       customerID brand  transactionID                      
Afiliates Amazon  2022-11-01 01         Amazon 51000          [firetv, alexa]  100
                  2022-11-10 01         Amazon 53000                 [firetv]   40
                  2022-11-15 02         Amazon 54000                 [firetv]   50
          Awin    2022-11-05 01         Ponto  55000                  [alexa]   50
```